# CLion and multiple projects with DLL's

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

I have one project that when built will create a DLL.

Is it possible to have two projects open with CLion so that they can both be built and the second project uses the DLL?

Sort of like how you can have multiple projects in a solution in VS?

Comment: It's not about IDE, it's about how you configure `cmake` in your `CMakeLists.txt`\

Comment: Any ideas on how I would go about doing it to match what I'd like?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with `cmake`, then you better look for step by step tutorials

Comment: First of all, open `CMakeLists.txt` and create some targets for executable and library, and link the executable against the library